# Python + Leetcode: Test cases are "leaking over"/"interfering" with each other for recursive problems/code solutions?

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

So I was working on [Leetcode #39-Combination Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/) . And my test cases appear to be "leaking over/interfering" (best choice of words I could come up with) with each other:

For example, when I run the first test case (candidates =
[2,3,6,7]; target = 7), it passes successfully with the output being [[2,2,3],[7]] ✅.

However, when I run the 2nd test case (candidates =[2,3,5]; target = 8), it doesn't pass ❌. The output [[2,2,3],[7],[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]]. Strangely, I noticed that [2,2,3] and[7] are not only wrong because they don't sum up to target =8, but they are the output arrays of the previous test case.

Likelwise, when I run the 3rd test case (candidates=[2], target=1), my output [[2,2,3],[7],[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]], which is not only completely wrong❌ but also exactly the same as the last test case's output. This is even stranger bc how can a [2] and target=1 produce 5 different combos with numbers containing 3,5,7 which aren't even in candidates = []?

I wrote my code in Python, and I utilized a recursive backtracking solution (note-I did not use inner functions-not sure how much of a difference that would make otherwise though?):

```
import copy
class Solution(object):
    result = []
    def dfs(self, index, cur_list, total_sum, candidates, target):
        if total_sum == target:
            self.result.append(copy.copy(cur_list))
            return
        if total_sum > target or index >= len(candidates):
            return
        cur_list.append(candidates[index])
        self.dfs(index, cur_list, total_sum + candidates[index], candidates, target)
        cur_list.pop()
        self.dfs(index + 1, cur_list, total_sum, candidates, target)

    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        self.dfs(0, [], 0, candidates, target)
        return self.result
```

Comment: `result` is a class attribute. So all the `Solution` instances share the same value. The second test case will append to the list that was built during the previous test case. You should make it an instance attribute that you initialize in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the response :) I'm still kind of confused-Does it something like this
`def __init__(self, candidates, target): 
        self.candidates = candidates
        self.target = target
        self.result = []
`

Comment: I don't know why you need `self.candidates` and `self.target`. But it's correct for `self.result`